# AJAX Multiple File Upload to be Converted to Dropzone

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone

Hi I would like to seek help on how can I convert my regular Multiple Select Form Upload using AJAX to a Dropzone?

Below is my existing code:

```
<form name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
     <select class="form-control" id="templateName" name="templateName">
         <option value="">-Select Template-</option>                                                     
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
     <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="xml_file[]" id="xml_file" multiple>
     <button type="button" id="upload">Upload</button>
</form>

<script>

    $("#upload").on("click", function(){
         formData = new FormData($("form[name='uploadForm']")[0]);

         $.ajax({
           url: 'ajax-file-upload',
           headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           },
           type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           dataType: 'text',
           cache: false,  
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
           }
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
<script>
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

/* Dropzone Configuration */
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#uploadForm", { 
   autoProcessQueue: false,
   parallelUploads: 50 // Number of files process at a time (default 2)
});

$("#upload").on("click", function(){
   formData = new FormData($("form[name='uploadForm']")[0]);

     $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax-file-upload',
       headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       },
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       dataType: 'text',
       cache: false,  
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
       }
     });
 });
</script>
```

However it only returns me formdata for the select option tag,
 I know `myDropzone.files` can return me the files to be uploaded but how do I make it the same exact formdata that I passed on originally. Because I need to access the `xml_file` data on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I already come up with the solution,

(1) first I need to retain the `<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="xml_file[]" id="xml_file" multiple>` , you may hide it if you totally want to upload just by dropping the files, otherwise leave it visible.

(2) Upload Clicking Upload Button, I will need to set and update the value of the `formData`. To update my `formData` I need to append input name `xml_file[]`
 with 
`.dropzone.getAcceptedFiles()`. This is how we access dropzone accepted files, loop into this array to see all the accepted files.

See below for reference, there's still a lot of room for improvement, I will just leave it like this for now.

```
 <script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    /* Dropzone Configuration */
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#uploadForm", { 
       autoProcessQueue: false,
       parallelUploads: 50 // Number of files process at a time (default 2)
    });

    $("#upload").on("click", function(){
       formData = new FormData($("form[name='uploadForm']")[0]);

         $.each($("form[name='uploadForm']")[0].dropzone.getAcceptedFiles(), 
             function(a,b){
            formData.append('xml_file[]', $("form[name='uploadForm']")[0].dropzone.getAcceptedFiles()[a]);
         });

         $.ajax({
           url: 'ajax-file-upload',
           headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           },
           type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           dataType: 'text',
           cache: false,  
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
           }
         });
     });
    </script>
```